# Haskell, No instance for (Show ([String, Int)] -> Int

Tags: haskell, happy

Trying to compile Haskell.Happy example here: http://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-using.html#sec-other-datatypes, after generating .hs file with happy, I'm getting the

```
No instance for (Show ([String, Int)] -> Int
```

error, trying to compile it, while first part of the example compiled and run fine

what am I doing wrong?

Edit: Full error message

```
No instance for (Show ([(String, Int)] -> Int))
  arising from a use of `print'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Show ([(String, Int)] -> Int))
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `print'
In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `print . calc . lexer'
In the expression: getContents >>= print . calc . lexer
```

I'm running

```
ghc example.hs
```

and the line is

```
main = getContents >>= print . calc . lexer
```

The possible duplicate question's answer is to pass an environment, but how could I do it here?

Comment: I think the linked answer is right, but this implies an error in the Happy documentation. Load up your `example.hs` in `ghci` and ask it what type `calc` is (`:t calc`). I suspect you'll find it needs a `[(String, Int)]` parameter which isn't being satisfied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`calc` is probably of type `[Token] -> [(String,Int)] -> Int`, hence main should be:

`main = getContents >>= print . ($ []) . calc . lexer`

NOTE: The list in `($ [])` is the environment